# MYSQL - find count using group by take time

Tags: mysql, count

I want to find product's color including count of products in a specific color and i am using below mentioned query. Query executed successfully however it takes time around 2 sec. and we have 10 more filters having same query. I would like to inform you that i have created index all necessary fields

```
SELECT Count(c.url_key) AS pcount, 
   c.color_name, 
   c.url_key        AS purl_key, 
   c.color_id 
FROM   products AS p 
   INNER JOIN colors AS c 
           ON p.color_id = c.color_id 
   INNER JOIN product_filters AS f 
           ON p.color_id = f.filter_id 
   INNER JOIN product_price AS pp 
           ON p.product_id = pp.product_id 
WHERE  p.approved = 1 
GROUP  BY c.url_key 
ORDER  BY pcount DESC
```

Explain colors listed below:

```
Field       Type         Null   Key Default Extra
----------- ------------ ------ --- ------- --------------
color_id    int(11)      NO     PRI NULL    auto_increment
color_name  varchar(255) NO     MUL NULL
color_code  varchar(7)   NO     MUL NULL
url_key     varchar(255) NO     UNI NULL
status      tinyint(1)   NO     MUL 1
```

Please suggest

Comment: What indexes? And what is the output of `explain select ...`?

Comment: You can edit your question and add necessary info.

Comment: Add.it.to.the.question

Comment: Field Type Null Key Default Extra  <br>
color_id int(11) NO PRI NULL auto_increment  <br>
color_name varchar(255) NO MUL NULL  <br/>  
color_code varchar(7) NO MUL NULL  <br> 
url_key varchar(255) NO UNI NULL  <br> 
status tinyint(1) NO MUL 1  <br>

Comment: You added this into a comment now like 10 times. ADD IT TO THE QUESTION INSTEAD!

Comment: Hi juergen,
i have updated question. Please check now